# Emberjs / Ember-Data: Working with multiple REST Servers (hosts)?

Tags: rest, ember.js

I'm fairly new to emberjs, but loving it thus far.

I have ember-data hooked up and communicating with a REST API fine using
`App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ host: '...' });`

So far so good.  But happens when I need to talk to more than one host during the course of the same application?

I'm guessing I can create a second adapter and a second store and then specify which adapter to use for each store?  Is this the preferred method, or is there a different cleaner way to deal with this?

Can you provide an example of:

- Initializing a custom store using a named adapter
- Making a store.find call to that specific named store?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access separate hosts on a per-model basis, you can specify per-model adapters:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  // ...
});

App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  // ...
});
```

Ember will automatically use the `App.PostAdapter` when you are using `App.Post`.

[Reference](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#per-type-adapters)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I am absolutely blown away by how easy ember makes this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't use a different store, you'd just use different adapters with different hosts, per type.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RestAdapter.extend({ host: 'foo'});

App.ColorsAdapter = DS.RestAdapter.extend({ host: 'bar'});
```

Or if you have a plethora on one host, and a plethora on another host.

```
App.FooAdapters = DS.RestAdapter.extend({ host: 'foo'});

App.ColorsAdapter = App.FooAdapters.extend();
```

Comment: ouch. 1 minute late. i like the {host} addition pointing out the simplicity of extending an adapter with only one unique parameter